# How can I pull data from my database using the Django ORM that annotates values for each day?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I have a Django app that is attached to a MySQL database. The database is full of records - several million of them.

My models look like this:

```
class LAN(models.Model):
    ...

class Record(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(...)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(...)

    ip_address = models.CharField(...)
    LAN = models.ForeignKey(LAN, related_name="records", ...)

    bytes_downloaded = models.BigIntegerField(...)
    bytes_uploaded = models.BigIntegerField(...)
```

Each record reflects a window of time, and shows if a particular IP address on particular LAN did any downloading or uploading during that window.

What I need to know is this:
    Given a beginning date, and end date, give me a table of which DAYS a particular LAN had ANY activity (has any records)

Ex:

> Between Jan 1 and Jan 31, tell me which DAYS LAN A had ANY records on
>   them

Assume that once in a while, a LAN will shut down for days at a time and have no records or any activity on those days.

My Solution:

I can do this the slow way by attaching some methods to my LAN model:

```
class LAN(models.Model):
    ...

    # Returns True if there are records for the current LAN between 2 given dates
    # Returns False otherwise
    def online(self, start, end):
        criterion1 = Q(start_time__lt=end)
        criterion2 = Q(end_time__gt=start)

        return self.records.filter(criterion1 & criterion2).exists()

    # Returns a list of days that a LAN was online for between 2 given dates
    def list_online_days(self, start, end):

        start_date = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime.strptime(start, "%b %d, %Y"))
        end_date = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime.strptime(end, "%b %d, %Y"))
        end_date = end_date.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999)

        days_online = []
        current_date = start.astimezone()

        while current_date <= end:
            start_of_day = current_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
            end_of_day = current_date.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999)

            if self.online(start=start_of_day, end=end_of_day):
                days_online.append(current_date.date())

            current_date += timezone.timedelta(days=1)

        return days_online
```

At which point, I can run:

```
lan = LAN.objects.get(id=1) # Or whatever LAN I'm interested in
days_online = lan.list_online_days(start="Jan 1, 2020", end="Jan 31, 2020")
```

This works, but results in one query being run per day between my start date and end date. In this case, 31 queries (Jan 1, Jan 2, etc.).
This makes it really, really slow for large time periods, as it needs to go through all the records in the database 31 times. Database indexing helps, but it's still slow with enough data in the database.

Is there a way to do a single database query to give me what I need?

I feel like it would look something like this, but I can't quite get it right:

```
lan.records.filter(criterion1 & criterion2).annotate(date=TruncDay('start_time')).order_by('date').distinct().values('date').annotate(exists=Exists(SOMETHING))
```

The first part:

```
lan.records.filter(criterion1 & criterion2).annotate(date=TruncDay('start_time')).order_by('date').distinct().values('date')
```

Seems to give me what I want - one value per day, but I'm not sure how to annotate the result with an exists field that shows if any records exist on that day.

Note: This is a simplified version of my app - not the exact models and fields, so if certain things could be improved, like not using CharField for the ip_address field, don't focus too much on that

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being simpler than I thought, mostly because I already had it.

This:

```
lan.records.filter(criterion1 & criterion2).annotate(date=TruncDay('start_time')).order_by('date').distinct().values('date').annotate(exists=Exists(Record.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('pk'))))
```

Was what I was expecting, but all it does is return `exists=True` for all days returned, which is accurate, but not overly helpful. This is because any days that had no records on them are already omitted from the results.

That means I can skip the entire annotate section, and just do this:

```
lan.records.filter(criterion1 & criterion2).annotate(date=TruncDay('start_time')).order_by('date').distinct().values('date')
```

which already gives me a list of datetime objects when there were records present, and skips any where there weren't.